# Python multiprocessing.Pool slower than sequential execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I'm trying to write a program that operates on a long list of elements (the list is called *training_set* in the code example). Each row of the list contains two numbers that have to be found on another list called *IDs*: hence, my program iterates on *training_set*'s rows and, for each of them, finds the corresponding 2 numbers in *IDs* and then performs some more computation (not shown in the code).

With sequential execution, this requires about 300s. Since each row of *training_set* is indipendend from the others, I was thinking of parallelizing the computation by splitting the input by the #cpu_cores, using **multiprocessing.Pool**.
However, the parallelized version is slower than the sequential one.

```
num_procs = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

with open("training_set.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    training_set  = list(reader)
training_set = [element[0].split(" ") for element in training_set]

with open("node_information.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    node_info  = list(reader)
IDs = [element[0] for element in node_info]

batch_size = int(len(training_set)/num_procs)
inputs=[]

# split list into batches to feed to the different threads
for i in range(num_procs):
    if i == (num_procs-1): inputs.append(list(training_set[int(i*batch_size):(len(training_set)-1)]))
    else: inputs.append(list(training_set[int(i*batch_size): int((i+1)*batch_size)]))

def init(IDs):
    global identities
    identities = copy.deepcopy(IDs)

def analyze_pairs(partialList):
    pairsSet = copy.deepcopy(partialList)
    for i in range(len(pairsSet)):
        source = pairsSet[i][0] # an ID of edges
        target = pairsSet[i][1] # an ID of edges
        ## find an index maching to the source ID
        index_source = identities.index(source)
        index_target = identities.index(target)
        ***additional computation***

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(num_procs, initializer=init, initargs=(IDs,))
    training_features = pool.map(analyze_pairs, inputs)
```

I'm not showing the rest of the code of the for loop (at the end of *analyze_pairs()*) because the problem persists even if i remove that code, hence it's not there that the problem resides.)

I know that there are already many questions on this topic, but I couldn't find a solution for my case. 
I don't think that here parallelism introduces more overhead than speedup because the input of each thread is large (on a 8 threads cpu, each thread should take at least 35s) and there is no explicit message passing. I also tried to use **copy.deepcopy** to make sure that each thread works on a separate list(althought it shouldn't be a problem since each thread only performs 'read' actions on the list), but it didn't work.

What could the problem be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might be loading the files multiple times which could take a long time; maybe put the file loading code into the `__main__`?

Comment: @SamMason i tried but it didn't help, anyway thank you for your answer ;)

Comment: my guess is still around file loading time; have you tried adding `print` statements at various points in the code to figure out where your time is going?